# How to split the input value based on separator and push them into an array?

Tags: javascript, string, input, split

For the purposes of this answer, please know that I am a "hello, World!-level beginner and still learning the basics.

Onward:

I am attempting to take user input and place it into an array, breaking the string at each tilde (~).

I have mostly grabbed this script from other sources (Thanks, StackOverflow!) and have edited it to suit (breaking it too many times to count) my purposes. I feel I am quite close to an answer, but close is no cigar:

Currently this code breaks on tilde, but still stores the (split) text as a single string, when I need it to store as individual strings instead.

I... assume that I need to somehow store the split strings as separate numerals (1,2,etc.) as per x=1, but I am not sure how to do that. Thoughts?

```js
var x = 1;
var notesArray = Array();

window.add_element_to_array = function add_element_to_array()
{
 notesArray[x] = document.getElementById("text1").value.split('~');
 alert("Element: " + notesArray[x] + " Added at index " + x);
 x++;
 document.getElementById("text1").value = "";
}

window.display_array = function display_array()
{
   var e = "<hr/>";   

   for (var y=1; y<notesArray.length; y++)
   {
     e += "Element " + y + " = " + notesArray[y] + "<br/>";
   }
   document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = e;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text1"/>
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Add"  onclick="add_element_to_array();"/>
<input type="button" id="button2" value="Display"  onclick="display_array();"/>
<div id="Result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting the input string "a~b" on the "~" character creates: `["a", "b"]`. You're pushing this array to the `notesArray`'s indices. So, you end up creating a 2-dimensional array like this: `[["a", "b"], ["c", "d"],...]`

When you concatenate those individual arrays to the sting `e`, it *coerces* them to create a comma separated string ("a,b"). So, it's not exactly adding the full string to the `notesArray` as you assumed.

If you want individual `split` strings to be added into the `notesArray`, you can use [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) or [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) instead

Here's a working snippet: (Click on `Run code snippet` to test it out)

```js
var notesArray = Array();

function add_element_to_array() {
  let splits = document.getElementById("text1").value.split('~');

  // loop through each item splits and push it to notesArray
  for (var i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
    notesArray.push(splits[i]);
  }

  /*
  // you can also do this using concat:
  notesArray = notesArray.concat(splits);
  
  // or using the new spread syntax
  notesArray.push(...splits);
  */

  document.getElementById("text1").value = "";
}

function display_array() {
  var e = "<hr/>";

  for (var y = 0; y < notesArray.length; y++) {
    e += "Element " + y + " = " + notesArray[y] + "<br/>";
  }
  document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = e;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text1"></input>
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Add" onclick="add_element_to_array();"></input>
<input type="button" id="button2" value="Display" onclick="display_array();"></input>
<div id="Result"></div>
```

(Also, I have changed the `for` loop to start from `0` in `display_array` function since array indices start from `0`)

Comment: I see. So it still created two arrays, it just then concats them into a single array after?

This works quite well for what I need - I just want to be sure I understand the chain of events happening. Thank you so much!

Comment: It creates a new array merging `notesArray` and `splits` array. Since it creates a new array and doesn;t actually update the `notesArray`, we are assinging back the merged array to `notesArray`

Comment: @nadanada Wait let me add a `push` alternative with a for loop

Comment: I see. Thank you for this.

Comment: @nadanada Updated answer with a  `push` option. Now we are looping through each individual split item in the `splits` array and *pushing* it to the `notesArray`. Unlike `concat`, `push` actually changes the original array. So, you don't need to reassign. Click on the links on "push" and "concat" in the answer for documentation.

Comment: Thank you much. I'll play around with it a bit, see if I learn something (like getting it to push by string, and not the whole array :)